# htaccess wordpress help needed with other custom php project in subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a wp website and recently I developed another custom php project which is located inside /selfie directory of wp installation. My skills with htaccess and rewriterules are not great.

So far my wp site has no .htaccess file the proble is that it can not load css and js files.

Is there a way by creating an htaccess file to allow the project in that subdirectory to work as expected?

This is what I have tried so far without success by uploading an htaccess file next to wp index.php.

case 1:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryname1/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectoryname2/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

Case 2:

Also from what I've read if I placed an empty htaccess file inside my selfie directory it should override anything else and work? but it does not...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: How is your custom project related to WP?

Comment: it is not in any way it's just a couple of php pages inside selfie directory. The thing is that those php files do not load css or js files located inside selfie/css/ and selfie/js directories

Comment: You should edit your post so it reflects the real problem. You have a project but can't get CSS and JS files to work. Add the code (PHP/HTML) you are using to include those CSS/JS files